# spiderable: phantomjs failed: null

Tags: meteor

I have been trying to figure out an issue with spiderable for several hours now. I have it installed and running beautifully on my local machine, but once I deploy to production I get this error `spiderable: phantomjs failed: null`. As you can see, this is not very helpful in debugging the issue.

I have followed all the advice in this excellent post on Meteorpedia, but to no avail:
http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable/

To make it even more strange, when I run the `phantomtest.js` script found on the page linked above, everything runs without any issue.

What I would really like to do is to be able to log some debug output from PhantomJS as it's being called by spiderable, but I have no idea if that's even possible. I tried messing around with spiderable code to pass some additional debugging parameters to PhantomJS, but that didn't work for me.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And now it's magically working for no apparent reason. I'm thrilled that it's working, but at the same time I really hate it when an issue just goes away like that. Now I will have to keep an eye on my log files on a daily basis to see if this issue starts popping up again.